# Redirect to OAuth URL with headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, flask

I'm trying to write a Python 3.5 Flask application that redirects a user to an OAuth URL, for authentication / authorization. As part of that redirection, I have to include the `Authorization` header. The built-in `redirect()` method in Flask doesn't seem to support adding HTTP headers.

What's the proper way of handling this in such an application?

Comment: Have you tried using https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I haven't given that a try, no. I was trying to understand the raw process, but I may end up incorporating something like that eventually. It says it's only compatible with oAuth 1.0a, and there are quite a few oAuth 2.0 services out there.

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, there's an OAuth 2 example for Flask here: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Python-Example. It doesn't appear to be redirecting, though.

Comment: I see that, yeah. Any ideas on what the proper method of redirecting would be, including HTTP headers? I'll take a look at the source for the Flask-oAuth package.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to build your own response object to add headers. You can check out the docs here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response

A simple example for your use case would be something like:

```
response = Response(headers={'Authorization': 'whatever'},
                    is_redirect=True,
                    url="https://your-redirected-url.com")
return response
```

Edit: Further info

Also, I would check out https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib if you are interested in using a library. It has support for oAuth1 and oAuth2 and it is relatively easy to setup with a standard Flask app.

Edit: Another way of doing it

This morning I remembered a simpler way to do this. You can call the redirect function and it will return a flask Response object. Then you are able to set the headers on that newly created object.

```
response = redirect('https://url')
response.headers = {'authorization': 'whatever'}  
return response
```

Comment: Thanks, but according to Python 3.5's requests library, the Response() class is not callable. Therefore, I can't instantiate it. Any thoughts?

Comment: The above answer is using flasks Response class. I will update with an additional solution that does not create it's own Response object.

Comment: The above answer is using an addon module, not the flasks Response class.

Comment: Some update ? I need the same thing, i need to get the username and password and add the others data to get a token, but it looks hard

Comment: I'm using python3 and I get this error:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_redirect'