# Auth0 redirect call is blocked by CORS policy

Tags: python, flask, cors

I am building a web application with the backend in Python and a frontend in JS.

I want to perform the authentication in the backend as I want to safeguard the data on my SQL server (currently mocked with SQLite).

I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: Cross-origin redirection to https://dev-itzm1yscqn6c5uyu.eu.authO.com/u/login?... 
denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 302
```

I have tried to add CORS policies and Origin to the header. However, authentication and CORS are quite new to me, so I don't know where to look.

My Python code:

```
import sqlite3
import sys
from os import environ as env
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
from functools import wraps

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, redirect, session, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode

ENV_FILE = find_dotenv()
if ENV_FILE:
    load_dotenv(ENV_FILE)

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

app.secret_key = env.get("APP_SECRET_KEY")

oauth = OAuth(app)

oauth.register(
    "auth0",
    client_id=env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret=env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    # client_kwargs={
    #     "scope": "openid profile email",
    # },
    server_metadata_url=f'https://{env.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")}/.well-known/openid-configuration',
)


def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        # Check if the user is authenticat  ed (e.g., by verifying session, cookies, or tokens).
        if not is_user_authenticated():
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

def is_user_authenticated():
    print('ok', sys.stdout)
    return 'user_id' in session

@app.route("/callback", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def callback():
    token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
    print(token, sys.stdout)
    session["user"] = token
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(
        redirect_uri=url_for("callback", _external=True)
    )

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(
        "https://"
        + env.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")
        + "/v2/logout?"
        + urlencode(
            {
                "returnTo": url_for("/", _external=True),
                "client_id": env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
            },
            quote_via=quote_plus,
        )
    )

# Create SQLite database and table
conn = sqlite3.connect('medication.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS intakes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp DATETIME, medication TEXT, dosage TEXT, remarks TEXT)')
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, typical_dosage TEXT, notes TEXT)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

@app.route('/api/saveIntake', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
@cross_origin()
def save_intake():
    data = request.json

    timestamp = data['timestamp']
    medication = data['medication']
    dosage = data['dosage']
    remarks = data['remarks']

    # Save data to the SQLite database

    conn = sqlite3.connect('medication.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO intakes (timestamp, medication, dosage, remarks) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (timestamp, medication, dosage, remarks))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Data saved successfully'})

@app.route('/api/saveItem', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
@cross_origin()
def save_item():
    data = request.json

    name = data['name']
    typical_dosage = data['typical_dosage']
    notes = data['notes']

    # Save data to the SQLite database

    conn = sqlite3.connect('medication.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO items (name, typical_dosage, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (name, typical_dosage, notes))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Data saved successfully'})

@app.route('/api/getItems', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
@cross_origin()
def get_items():


    conn = sqlite3.connect('medication.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM items')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    return data

@app.route('/api/getIntakes', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
@cross_origin()
def get_intakes():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('medication.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM intakes')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    
    return data

@app.route('/api/deleteIntake', methods=['DELETE'])
@login_required
@cross_origin()
def delete_intake():
    return validate_and_delete("intakes", request.args.get('id'))

@app.route('/api/deleteItem', methods=['DELETE'])
@login_required
@cross_origin()
def delete_item():
    return validate_and_delete("items", request.args.get('id'))

def validate_and_delete(tablename, item_id):

    if item_id is None:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing item ID'}), 400
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('medication.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    print(tablename,file=sys.stdout)

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE ID = ?', (item_id,))
    item = cursor.fetchone()

    if item is None:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Item not found'}), 404


    cursor.execute(f'DELETE FROM  {tablename} WHERE ID = ?', (item_id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Item deleted successfully'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In my javascript code the error comes when I perform the following fetch:

```
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/getItems", {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
        }
    })
```

The details of my request in the browser:

```
Summary
URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/getItems
URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/login
URL: https://dev-itzm1yscqn6c5uyu.eu.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=x5SG9Q3SVfGIR9M7V0YYlswA9yOA7dd6&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Fcallback&state=CUtwHdd6r0zJdAZYEFFh2HCvNcLhsw
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
index.js:128

Request
GET /api/getItems
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5500/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.15

Redirect Response
302 FOUND
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 08:00:11 GMT
Location: /login
Vary: Origin

Request
GET /login
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5500/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.15

Redirect Response
302 FOUND
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 08:00:11 GMT
Location: https://dev-itzm1yscqn6c5uyu.eu.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=x5SG9Q3SVfGIR9M7V0YYlswA9yOA7dd6&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Fcallback&state=CUtwHdd6r0zJdAZYEFFh2HCvNcLhsw
Vary: Origin, Cookie

Request
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: null
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5500/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.15

Response
No response headers

Query String Parameters
response_type: code
client_id: x5SG9Q3SVfGIR9M7V0YYlswA9yOA7dd6
redirect_uri: http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback
state: CUtwHdd6r0zJdAZYEFFh2HCvNcLhsw
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific error is due to the 'Same-Origin' policy implemented in web browsers. This policy allows browsers to accept all responses from the same domain that is making the request. In this case, seems that you are using the localhost to make a request to a different server (https://dev-itzm1yscqn6c5uyu.eu.authO.com/u/login?..).

So, if the browser is blocking you the response, you can include the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin = '*' " header in the response (server-side). By doing this, the browser should permit the response regardless of the origin domain. This is not a very secure solution... but you can try to test where can be the problem. If it works, you can adjust the header with the proper information server.

There are other techniques like using a proxy server to bypass this.

Hope it could help you...

Comment: Thanks @Vicnroll

I was also trying this option, but I don't know how I can add it in the redirect (if this is at least where you are hinting at).

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553888/redirect-to-oauth-url-with-headers, but with no luck.